# Question about for loop arguments in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I've started learning python from scratch, coming with some rudamentary java knowledge. When I started learning about for loops I expected something in the likes of this:

```py
for n in range(0, len(list_name)):
    do this
```

as java supports a similar syntax. But then python surprised me with the following syntax:

```
for n in list_name:
    do this
```

After putting both of the for loop styles to use I've put together a simple example to see if they differ in function:

```py
example = [151, 145, 179]

total = 0
number = 0
avg = 0

for n in example: #imo the better variant
  total += n
  number += 1

avg = round(total/number)
print(f"The 1st for loop: {total, number, avg}")

total = 0
number = 0
avg = 0

for n in range(0, len(example)): #imo the superfluous variant
  total = total + example[n]
  number += 1

avg = round(total/number)
print(f"The 2nd for loop: {total, number, avg}")
```

Now, as far as I can see, they can be used interchangably. The first for loop is simpler in function and is quicker to type, the 2nd for loop is more "classic" programming I guess. Is there ever a use case for the 2nd type of for loop?

Comment: Sometimes you don't have an iterable object. In that case, you'd do simply `in range(100)`.

Comment: In regards to `for n in example`: you don't even need to keep track of number manually. You can use `for idx, n in enumerate(example): total+=n` And instead of `number` in `avg = round(total/number)` you could've just used `len(example)`.

Comment: As you note, the indexing variant is unnecessary when you don't care which index you are at. It tends to happen when C or PHP programmers try to write Python, and don't realize that the language is more expressive than theirs.

Comment: If you're interested about the index, the pythonic way is to use `enumerate`, and if you only use the index to pair two iterables, then the pythonic way is to use `zip`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a need for range(len(a))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184335/is-there-a-need-for-rangelena)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes there is a use case for the second type of for-loop. You can use it to keep track of the index of the elements in your iterable. See a refactored version of your code here:

**Use Case 1:**

```
total, avg = 0, 0

for n in range(0, len(example)):
  total += example[n]
  n += 1

avg = round(total/n)
print(f"The 2nd for loop: {total, n, avg}")
```

Notice the `number` variable in your example is no longer needed in the refactored version. This still outputs `The 2nd for loop: (475, 3, 158)`.

**Use Case 2:**
You can also use the `enumerate` function to do this:

```
total, avg = 0, 0

for i,j in enumerate(example):
  total += j
  i += 1

avg = round(total/i)
print(f"The 2nd for loop: {total, i, avg}")
```

Output is still the same `The 2nd for loop: (475, 3, 158)`.

Comment: Note that `enumerate` is actually the preferred and pythonic way to do this.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes and I've added a second use case. So OP can choose whichever he prefers.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Python is known for a very simplified syntax, that a human can read easily. In the back, there is a lot going on, when the code is executed.

## Differences

### For-loop

In your example, `for n in range(0, len(list_name))` is a classic for-loop. It will put every natural number starting from 0 to the length of the list called `list_name`, minus 1, in your n. So human translated it results in "for n=0, n=1, ..., n=length of list_name-1: do something".

Here you already imply the step size (1). Normally, range has three parameters: start, end and step size. In python, you can leave out everything except the end parameter, and python will then assume start = 0 and step size = 1. So you could have written `for n in range(len(list_name))` and gotten the same result as when specifying the start = 0 and implying the step size = 1.

In fact, `range(integer)` will create an "array" (not really, read the Bonus knowledge section) for you with the natural numbers 0 to integer-1 inside, that the for(each)-loop can iterate over.

```py
array = range(5)

for n in array:
    print(n)
```

and

```py
for n in range(5):
    print(n)
```

and

```py
for n in range(0, 5, 1):
    print(n)
```

and

```py
for n in range(0, 5):
    print(n)
```

will all result in

```bash
0
1
2
3
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note, that you can't just specify the range's end and step size, because it will then take your first parameter as start and the second parameter as end. So if you need to specify a step size, you also need to specify a start, because range() doesn't accept keyword arguments.

### Foreach-loop

Now when you use `for n in list_name:` instead, what you actually (human readably) say is: "take this list named list_name, and take every element value of it. then do something with this value." So here, your n=list_name[0], n=list_name[1], ..., n=list_name[-1] (-1 being the last element of a list). It is called a foreach-loop in other languages (for each element in an iterable, do something that may or may not involve this element).

They can be used interchangably in your example, because you are using different syntax in the body of the loop. Depending on the use case, both foreach and for loop can be better or worse.

### Use cases

#### For-loop example:

It can be useful to know how many times you have looped before breaking out of the loop, in that case, you have direct access to that number through the variable n (n-1, if you started at 0). Or maybe you want to use the value of n (number of times the loop has already iterated before) in the inner logic of your loop. Then the normal for-loop is good and saves you workarounds.

Or, as pointed out already, sometimes you just want to execute a loop n times, without a reference array to loop over. Then it's quicker to just iterate over range(n-1) or range(1, n).

#### Foreach-loop example:

Maybe you have an array of objects, and you want to print the `__str()__` (string representation) for all of these objects. Here, your number of iterations doesn't matter, you just want to read every object's string. In this case, a foreach-loop is better (`for object in object_list: print(str(object))`).

## Conclusion

Whether you should use a for- or foreach-loop depends on the body of the loop and there are valid use cases for both of them.

## Bonus knowledge

In fact, since Python 3, the range() function does not create an array anymore, but is a generator function. This means, the program running a range(1000) call will not have to put a 1000-item-array with natural numbers in your memory anymore. It will instead ask for "the next" element in that range, starting with 0, ending with 999, every time it runs the loop body (again).