# Access two consecutive elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I need to access the `n` and `n+1` elements of a list. For example, if my list was `[1,2,3,4,5]` and my nth element was `2`, I'd need the next element in the list, `3`.

Specifically, I need to access these elements in order to use them to look up a value in a matrix A

I have a for loop that's iterating over the list:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in list:
  value = A[i,i+1] #access A[1,2], A[2,3], A[3,4], A[4,5]
```

the problem with this is that I can't do an `i+1` operation to access the `n+1` element of my list. This is my first time programming in Python and I assumed element access would be the same as in C/C++ but it's not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: unrelated: `A[i,i+1]` doesn't return `i`-th and `i+1`-th elements in C/C++ (unless you create a type in C++ that behaves that way, you can do it in Python too). The common interpretation, especially if `A` is a matrix is to return a single element from `i`-th row and `i+1`-th column e.g., `numpy` arrays do this.

Comment: The duplicate is about non overlapping chunk while this is overlapping.

Comment: Better dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [slicing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) like this

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(A) - 1):
    value = A[i:i+2]
```

The [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function lets you iterate `len(A) - 1` times.

Comment: another way is ...     `A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    print [(x,y)for x, y in zip(A[:-1], A[1:])]`

Comment: how do we set up the code so that the output is of the form [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]. ....

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate can give you access to the index of each item:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(A[:-1]):
    value = A[i:i+2]
```

If all you need are the pairs of data:

```
for value in zip(A, A[1:]):
    value
```