# How can I check a previous index when iterating through a for loop python

Tags: python

I have a list that is somewhat random.

```
list  = [1,2,4,2,25,3,2,4,2,1,1,32,3,3,2,2,23,4,2,2,2,34,234,33,2,4,3,2,3,4,2,1,3,4,3]
```

I want to iterate through it and do something like this:

```
for item in list:
    while item >=5:
        if item = item_5_indexes_ago
            print "its the same as it was 5 entries ago!"
```

Obviously, item_5_indexes_ago is not valid python. What should I substitute here? I want to check if list[5]==list[1], if list[6]==list[2], ..... for every item in the list.

Comment: Note: that's 4 indexes ago.

Comment: I don't know Python, but it seems like you can just calculate "index-5" and use that for the comparison.  Example: if item[6] = item[6-5] ....

Comment: What is the end goal? That may help come up with a proper solution.

Comment: Wow, 5 answers and no one's suggested `zip`.

Comment: This question is about "this and the next", but perhaps it is also helpful for "this and 4 items before" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python

Comment: @MikeN: the end goal is the computation of a moving average. this is a simplified version of the part I am having trouble with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pythonic solution is to use the builtin `enumerate` to keep track of the index as well as the item

```
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if index >= 5:
        item_5_indexes_ago = my_list[index-5]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use list comprehension and `enumerate` function to get the elements:

```
[l for i, l in enumerate(list[:-5]) if l == list[i+5]]
```

Comment: Although the list comprehension is nice, there is a lot of information loss here - it's impossible to say for which indices there were matches. I'm not sure if it's what OP needs in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You can loop thorugh indices instead:

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    # do something with
    # list[i]
```

and to access to a previous element, you can use:

```
if i >= 4 and list[i] == list[i - 4]:
    print "its the same as it was 4 entries ago!"
```

**Notes:**

- Since you want to check `list[5]==list[1]` and `if list[6]==list[2]` it seems like you want to check for an element **4** indices before, not 5.
- Don't use `list` as the name of a variable because it will *hide* its built-in implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method to do this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    if index>=5:
        if item == list[index-5]:
            print "It's the same as it was 5 entries ago!"
```

Answer (score 0):

A more convenient loop in this case would be to loop by index, like this:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    if i >= 5 and list[i] == list[i-5]:
        print "it's the same as it was 5 entries ago!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `list[5:]` and `list[:-5]` in parallel with `zip`:

```
for item, item_5_indices_ago in zip(list[5:], list[:-5]):
    do_whatever_with(item, item_5_indices_ago)
```

Since `zip` stops when the shortest input sequence does, you can replace `list[:-5]` with just `list`. Also, don't call your list `list`, or when you try to call the `list` built-in, you'll get a weird `TypeError`.

Answer (score -1):

Just step through the list in groups of 6:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

for fives in grouper(biglist, 6):
    if fives[:-1].count(fives[-1]) > 1:
       print("its the same!")
```

Comment: This does something completely different from what the questioner is trying to do.