# python TypeError: str object is not an iterator

Tags: python, string, search, printing

I'm writing a code which searches in a text file for a value and print the previous line; 
but I faced 2 problems , First I didn't find a way to print the previous line and when  I wrote the code to print the next value I got an error .

Code :-

```
with open('Perfix/prefix.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "100" in line:
            print (next(line))
```

Supposed Scenario :-

The code should search in prefix.txt file to find the line with the value 100 exactly then it should print the previous line . Thats it !!

Error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 7, in <module>
    print next(line)
TypeError: str object is not an iterator
```

What is the error ? Also could you please advise how to print the "previous" not the next line ?

Example :-

File prefix.txt

```
00
122
141
1525
1162
1547
100
125
15321
1100
1513
142100
```

Output :-

```
1547
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead? Why did you use `next()` here at all?

Comment: keep track of previous line and just print it if 100 is in the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to find a previous line, is to just store the line each time it didn't match:

```
with open('Perfix/prefix.txt') as f:
    previous = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '100':
            print previous
        previous = line
```

Note that you do not need to read all lines into memory first; just loop over the file object.

The `next()` function is not something you should be using here at all; it requires an iterator and would advance it to the *next* item, not rewind it to a previous entry.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear - `line` is a `str`ing, not an iterator, so `next(line)` makes no sense. Consider:

```
next('hello')
```

What should happen?

---

To deal with your problem, I would suggest something like:

```
for index, line in enumerate(lines): # get the index for each line as we go
    if index and line.strip() == '100': # if this isn't the first line & is just '100'
        print lines[index-1] # print the previous line
        break # optional - stop iterating if you don't want to find further lines
```

or iterate over the lines in pairs; see e.g. [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5434891/3001761).

Note also that you can do this *after* the file is closed:

```
 with open(...) as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
 for index, line in enumerate(lines):
     ...
```

Comment: thx bro your code is working but when i used it when the file has a string like that "015100" it also being included , I just need the FIRST EXACT MATCH ...

Comment: What do you mean *"exact match"*? Why are you using `in`? Do you mean `line == '100\n'`?

Comment: @MohammedAldaoudi: you do need to tell us *in your question* what you are trying to do, not just ask about an error you don't understand.

Comment: sorry , you can see the supposed scenario what i want the code to do , please check the edit

Answer (score 1):

Through `re` module.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    print re.findall(r'(?m)^(.*)\n100$', lines)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
1547
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                         matching start and end of line) (case-
                         sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                         (matching whitespace and # normally)
^                        the beginning of a "line"
(                        group and capture to \1:
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                           times)
)                        end of \1
\n                       '\n' (newline)
100                      '100'
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                         "line"
```

Comment: A regex is overkill here, and would require reading the whole file into memory. You can't do this if the file is sufficiently large.