# Python Excel if a condition is true print next line t+1

Tags: python, import-from-csv

**UPDATE:**

I want python to print the next line like t+1 in the excel file into python output window when a condition is met . I believe the problem lies in this part of the code

```
 print "FA",row[0], ','.join(row[1:])
```

This prints the present day I need python to print the next day (t+1)

I tried `print "FA",row[0], ','.join(row[1:]).nextline()`
but that does not work

for example 
lets say the excel file has

```
35F 1,0,1,0,1,1,1
66F 1,0,1,0,0,0,0

35F 1,0,1,0,1,1,1<-- at this moment python prints this part 

66F 1,0,1,0,0,0,0<--- **But I want python to print this {66F 1,0,1,0,0,0,0} this is the t+1**
```

Furthermore, here is the full code

```
import csv

with open('2015weather.csv', 'r') as file1:
     val = list(csv.reader(file1))[3]


with open('FAsince1900.csv', 'r') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2)
    reader.next() # this skips the first row of the file
    # this iteration will start from the second row of file2.csv
    for row in reader:
        if row[1:] == val:
            print print "FA",row[0], ','.join(row[1:])
```

**UPDATED 2:**
[image: this is goal]

Comment: do you want two print statements?

Comment: I think you may want something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/5434891/3001761, but it's not currently clear at all - what precisely is the problem with what you currently have?

Comment: @benolsen if all the rows are the same size you could you try using the `file.readline()` method

Comment: nope that doesn't work. please see update2

Comment: @ben does my below answer work for you?

Comment: @leekaiinthesky YES it WORKS :) you are a king !!!!! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
conditionMet = False
for row in reader:
    if conditionMet == True:
        print "FA",row[0], ','.join(row[1:])
        conditionMet = False # or break if you know you only need at most one line
    if row[1:] == val:
        conditionMet = True
```