# Python list manipulation: combine predecessor and successor to tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose I have a list `l` in python defined as:

```
l = [x1, x2, x3,...,xn-1, xn],
```

is there an easy way to create a list `l1`:

`l1 = [(x1, x2), (x2, x3),...,(xn-1, xn)]?`

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and `zip` two slices of the list together, which are offset by 1 index

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> [(a,b) for a,b in zip(l[:-1], l[1:])]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: list for range(10) is not needed here.

Comment: You can just do `zip(l, l[1:])`, since the arguments to `zip` don't need to be the same length.

Comment: What even shorter is `>>> zip(l, l[1:])`