# On python, how do you test to see whether a letter is preceded by another letter?

Tags: python-3.4

for example: for a letter in a word, if the letter is preceded by a vowel..................

how would you write that in pythonic language

for example:
if a "h" is preceded by a "s" anywhere in a word, `return(True)`

```
the_word("bash")
True

the_word("sushi")
True
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your question is far too broad. It's basically "please introduce me to python", and that is not a *specific question*.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5434891/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = 'h'
b = 's'

if b+a in "bash": # True
  ..
if b+a in "hello": # False
  ..
if b+a in "sushi": # True
```

If you want this in a function, just have a and b as parameters