# Best way to check next iteration value

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, iteration

I want to write a line of code that checks `if` the iteration `i==someValue` and the next iteration `i==anotherValue` then write a line of code in the loop.

E.g

```
for line in file:
    if line[1]=='A' and if next(line[1]) == 'B'
    print("do something here")
```

How can I go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to store the value that you want for the first line as a control value. If the next line does not have the correct value - the control value is cleared. For example like:

```
file = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B']
control_value = ''
for line in file:
    if line == 'A':
        control_value = line
        continue
    if line == 'B' and control_value == 'A':
        print('Do something here')
    control_value = ''
```

Any values except 'A' will reset the control_value.

Comment: thanks, that seems like an effective way to do what I want.  I'll give it a shot.