# Iterate over 'zipped' ranges of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I often work with numpy arrays representing critical times in a time series. I then want to iterate over the ranges and run operations on them. Eg:

```
rngs = [0, 25, 36, 45, ...]
output = []
for left, right in zip(rngs[:-1], rngs[1:]):
      throughput = do_stuff(array[left:right])...
      output.append(throughput)
```

Is there a less awkward way to do this?

Comment: Assuming the `rngs` are irregular and `dostuff` can only work on one slice at a time, that looks good. But also look at `ufunc.reduceat`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python)

Comment: Though I think he wants something special for `numpy`; not just a list.

Answer (score 0):

You might use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) generator

```
rngs = [0, 25, 36, 45, ...]
output = []
for index, _ in enumerate(rngs[:-1]):
      throughput = do_stuff(array[index:index+1])...
      output.append(throughput)
```

in one line with comprehension list:

```
rngs = [0, 25, 36, 45, ...]
output = [do_stuff(array[index:index+1]) for index, _ in enumerate(rngs[:-1])]
```

Comment: I see no difference between this and `for index in range(len(rngs)-1):`, or `xrange()` for Python 2. Additionally, there is no tuple unwrapping like in `index, _` and you don't have to construct `rngs[:-1]`.