# Find difference between every two adjacent elements in a list using lambda expressions?

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have a list such as this:

```
lst = [1, 13, 5, 23, 22, 1, 2]
```

And I would like to find the difference between every two adjacent elements using a lambda expression to get this:

```
differences = [12, -8, 18, -1, -21, 1]
```

How would I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Does it have to be lambda expressions? May I ask why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Use an `inline for loop` with your `lambda`.  The loop will loop over the indexes then use the indexes to access the numbers from the array provided, adding adjacent indexes.

```
magicSubtract = lambda lst: [(lst[i] - lst[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(lst)-1)]
print(magicSubtract([1, 13, 5, 23, 22, 1, 2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use map:

```
map(lambda pair: pair[1] - pair[0], zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]))
```

apply list to the result if you want a list:

```
list(_)
# [12, -8, 18, -1, -21, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why lambda expression? For an in line solution you can use list comprehension:

```
[lst[i+1]-lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)-1)]
```