# How to make two iteration in for loop using for-in syntax

Tags: python-3.x

Assume I have a list and I am looping in it with for-in syntax. Can this be done with for-in syntax or better question would be what is the most pythonic way to do this?

```
l= ["ok", "item1", "nope", "item2", "nope", "item3", "ok", "item4"]
for item in l:
    if item == "ok":
        print(item + ": " + ... ) # Where ... should be next item
```

I want this code prints out something like

```
ok: item1
ok: item4
```

edit: A more clear list example would be like accourding to comments:

```
l= ["ok", "item1", "nope", "item2", "somevalue","nope", "item3", "ok", "item4"]
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the list has an even number of elements and it alternates between ok/nope and value?

Comment: nope it is not guarenteed. What guarenteed is item always comes after ok/nope . Let me edit question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l= ["ok", "item1", "nope", "item2", "nope", "item3", "ok", "item4"]
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    if item == "ok":
        print(f"{item}: {l[index + 1]}")
```

using `enumerate()` you can get the value *and* the index of the current item from your list. If the value of the current item == "ok", then print the next item from the list via `index + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is use `zip()` method and slicing:

```
l= ["nope", "ok", "item1", "nope", "item2", "somevalue","nope", "item3", "ok", "item4"]

for val1, val2 in zip(l[::1], l[1::1]):
    if val1 == 'ok':
        print('{} : {}'.format(val1, val2))
```

Prints:

```
ok : item1
ok : item4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l= ["ok", "item1", "nope", "item2", "nope", "item3", "ok", "item4"]
for itemno in range(len(l)):
    if l[itemno] == "ok":
        print(l[itemno] + ": " +l[itemno+1] )
```

i think no need to use zip or enumerate as they take some computations. so to making problem simple, just think simple.