# How to merge every two lines of a text file into a single string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to merge every two lines of a text file into a single string, with all the strings grouped into a single list. Example of text file:

```
This is an example text file
containing multiple lines
of text, with each line
containing words made out of letters
```

I want the code to create strings like this:

```
This is an example text file containing multiple lines
of text, with each line containing words made out of letters
```

I have tried some solutions but they were for Python 2, but i am working with Python 3.9

This is what code i currently have (i wrote it myself)

```
with open(filePath) as text: # filePath is a variable asking for input by user, the user is required to type the file path of the .txt.file
lineCount = 0
firstLine = ""
secondLine = ""
lineList = []
finalResultList = []



for line in text: # Appends all the lines of the file
    lineList.append(line)

for i in lineList: # Merges 2 lines at a time into a single one
    if lineCount == 0:
        firstLine = i
        lineCount += 1
    elif lineCount == 1:
        secondLine = i
        lineCount = 0
        finalResult = str(str(firstLine) + " " + str(secondLine))
        finalResultList.append(finalResult)
```

Comment: given your `lineList`, you can use the following: `[" ".join([lineList[i], lineList[i+1]]) for i in range(0, len(lineList), 2)]`.
or: `list(" ".join(l) for l in zip(lines[:-1:2], lines[1:None:2]))`

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Concise and Pythonic.

Comment: Is it assumed the file has an even number of lines?

Comment: @Moosefeather, OP will need to check len(lineList) and if not even, then join the last line separately. This is for sim's response

Comment: The bulk of the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python. I'm only reluctant to close as a duplicate because one also has to open the file and use that iterator (which is a trivial complication, to be honest).

Answer (score 3):

Based on @sim 's comment:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

res = [' '.join(lines[i: i+2]) for i in range(0, len(lines), 2)]
```

Note this works with an odd number of lines too.