# how to pair each 2 elements of a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this

```
attach=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','k']
```

I wanna pair each two elements that followed by each other:

```
lis2 = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'k')]
```

I did the following:

```
Category=[] 
for i in range(len(attach)):
    if i+1< len(attach):
        Category.append(f'{attach[i]},{attach[i+1]}')
```

but then I have to remove half of rows because it also give `'b' ,'c'` and so on. I thought maybe there is a better way

Comment: So you want your output like this? `lis2=[('a','b'),('c' ,'d'),('e','f'),('g','k')]` ?

Comment: is this pairing based on the index? In the pairing do you want to join these as string, or want to pair them as sublist ?

Comment: @PrakashDahal yes

Comment: @Anonymous I want list

Comment: @python_user No I don't want `('b' . 'c')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increment iterator i.e by `i` by 2 when moving forward

```
Category=[] 
for i in range(0, len(attach), 2):
    Category.append(f'{attach[i]},{attach[i+1]}')
```

Also, you don't need the `if` condition, if the `len(list)` is always even

Comment: I am surprised why it didn't come in my mind!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to achieve this as:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','k']
new_list = list(zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2]))
```

where `new_list` will hold:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'k')]
```

This will work to get only the pairs, i.e. if number of the elements in the list are odd, you'll loose the last element which is not as part of any pair.

**If you want to preserve the last *odd* element from `list` as single element `tuple` in the final list**, then you can use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) (in Python 3.x, or [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in Python 2.x) with *list comprehension* as:

```
from itertools import zip_longest # In Python 3.x
# from itertools import izip_longest ## In Python 2.x

my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h', 'k']
new_list = [(i, j) if j is not None else (i,) for i, j in zip_longest(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])]
```

where `new_list` will hold:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h'), ('k',)]
#   last odd number as single element in the tuple ^
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
lis2 = [(lis[i],lis[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(lis),2)]
lis2
```

You can use list comprehension