# How can I get the line of index + 1 when enumerating lines in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

I am reading through the lines of a file using the code `for index, line in enumerate(lines):`.  I can access the string of the current line using (line).

Is it possible to access the next line to look ahead?  I have tried to access this by using `next_line = line(index + 1)` but this is creating an error.

**Code**

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'a') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        prev_line = ""
        string_length = 60
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            next_line = line(index + 1)
            print(f'Index is {index + 1}')
            # Do something here
```

Comment: Is your actual goal really to "index" the file, or just to iterate lines pairwise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python)

Comment: Hi MisterMiyagi,
Thank you for your answer.  My goal is to look at the next line to see if it starts with a hyphens and if it does, then I will print the current line, so the next line (starting with a hypen) will begin with a hyphen.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you asking how to index a list??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line` is a string therefore you can not do what you need.
Try something like this:

```py
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'a') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        prev_line = ""
        string_length = 60
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            try:
                next_line = lines[index + 1]
            except IndexError:
                pass
            print(f'Index is {index + 1}')
            # Do something here
```

Comment: IMO, it's not so clean to have to use a try/except just to avoid an off-by-one error

Answer (score 1):

You can just access it from the list as you normally would, this will cause an exception on the last iteration so I added a check to prevent this:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'a') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        prev_line = ""
        string_length = 60
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            if index < len(lines) - 1:
                next_line = lines[index+1]
                print(f'Index is {index + 1}')
                # Do something here
```