# How to create a dictionary from a dictionary based on indexes

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I will try to easily explain my problem. I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dic = {
   'I2a1a': ['I2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1a2a1a2'],
   'I2a1b': ['I2a1b1a1a1b1a'],
   'I2a1b2': ['I2a1b2a']
}
```

Based on this dictionary, when the length of the value is > 1 I want to create a new dictionary that will look like this:

```
new_dic = {
   'I2a1a': 'I2a1a2', 'I2a1a2': 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1a2a': 'I2a1a2a1a2',
   'I2a1b': 'I2a1b1a1a1b1a',
   'I2a1b2': 'I2a1b2a'
}
```

As we can see for the key `'I2a1a'` in the first dictionary, each value (except the last value) is a key in the `new_dic` and the value associated with it is the index `n+1` from the values of the key `'I2a1a'` of the first dictionary.

I have no idea where to start my script!

Comment: Often when you have no idea where to start, it helps to write down the steps you would take if _you_ were to solve this problem without a computer. Then translate your algorithm to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often when you have no idea where to start, it helps to write down the steps you would take if *you* were to solve this problem without a computer. Then translate your algorithm to code. For instance:

1. Iterate over `dic.items()`
2. For each `key`-`value` pair, create a list containing the key, and then all elements of the `value` list.
3. [Iterate over consecutive pairs (`current_elem`, `next_elem`) in this new list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5434891/843953)
4. In this iteration, the `current_elem` is the key for the `new_dic`, and `next_elem` is the value.

Now let's write this as code:

```
dic = {'I2a1a': ['I2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1a2a1a2'],
       'I2a1b': ['I2a1b1a1a1b1a'],
       'I2a1b2': ['I2a1b2a']}

new_dic = {}

for key, value in dic.items(): # 1.
    new_elems = [key, *value]  # 2.
    for current_elem, next_elem in zip(new_elems[:-1], new_elems[1:]):  # 3.
        new_dic[current_elem] = next_elem  # 4.
```

which gives the desired `new_dic`:

```
{'I2a1a': 'I2a1a2', 'I2a1a2': 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1a2a': 'I2a1a2a1a2',
 'I2a1b': 'I2a1b1a1a1b1a',
 'I2a1b2': 'I2a1b2a'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand very well what you are asking even because on the first key you didn't add any index.
Anyway, I put down some code that you can edit and use for your needs:

```
dic = {'I2a1a': ['I2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1a2a1a2'], 'I2a1b': ['I2a1b1a1a1b1a'], 'I2a1b2': ['I2a1b2a']}


dic2 = {}


for element in dic:
    if len(dic[element]) >1:
        i=0
        while i<len(dic[element]):
            key = element + (str(i))
            dic2[key]=dic[element][i]
            i +=1
    else:
        dic2[element] = dic[element][0]
print(dic2)
```

The output is:

```
{'I2a1a0': 'I2a1a2', 'I2a1a1': 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1a2': 'I2a1a2a1a2', 'I2a1b': 'I2a1b1a1a1b1a', 'I2a1b2': 'I2a1b2a'
```