# Counting backwards

Tags: python

I've got a list organized like this :

```
[('down', 0.0098000000000000309), 
('up', 0.0015000000000000568), 
('down', 0.008900000000000019), 
('down', 0.023300000000000098), 
('down', 0.011599999999999944), 
('down', 0.0027000000000000357), 
('up', 0.0023999999999999577), 
('up', 0.0065000000000000613), 
('down', 0.0057000000000000384), 
('down', 0.018400000000000083), 
('up', 0.009300000000000086), 
('down', 0.0038000000000000256), 
('down', 0.00050000000000005596), 
('up', 0.0082000000000000961), .....
```

What would be the best way to "compare backwards?" , basically I want to return "yes" ( or whatever .. ) IF we`ve got a series of 2 "downs" followed by one "up" AND the second value is inferior to 0.0095 .

I hope he makes sense ..

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323750/) shows how to iterate over a list using a sliding window. The rest should be simple enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def frob(l):
    downcount = 0
    for ele in l:
        if downcount >= 2 and ele[0] == 'up' and ele[1] < 0.0095:
                return True
        downcount = (downcount + 1) if ele[0] == 'down' else 0
    return False
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a sliding window, and test on that:

```
def slidingwindow(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    first, second = iterator.next(), iterator.next()
    for next in iterator:
        yield (first, second, next)
        first, second = second, next

def testforcondition(data):
    for window in slidingwindow(data):
        direction = [w[0] for w in window]
        if direction == ['down', 'down', 'up'] and window[2][1] < 0.0095:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: But much more readable! :-) Even if the slidingwindow function lived in a utility module, I'd be able to suss out what the testforcondition function was doing, one year from now, in an instant.

Comment: Just goes to show, readability is often a subjective quality.

Comment: Maintainability is subjective too, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
def test(data):
  for x in xrange(2, len(data)):
    if data[x-2][0] is 'down' and data[x][x-1] is 'down' and data[x][0] is 'up' and data[x][1] < 0.0095:
      return True
  return False
```

Comment: Where is the test for 'up' after two 'down' values?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (although now with the third slice, this is not really pretty anymore):

```
def compback(l):
    return any(i1[0] == i2[0] == "down" 
               and i2[1] < 0.0095
               and i3[0] == "up"
               for i1, i2, i3 in zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]))
```

Comment: Same here: Where is the test for 'up' after two 'down' values?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I completely overlooked that. I have now edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in xrange(0, len(list) - 2):
    if list[index][0] == 'down' and list[index + 1][0] == 'down' and list[index + 2][0] == 'up' and list[index + 1][1] < 0.0095:
         return True
```