# Sorting a list in Python without repeat previous item

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, loops, organization

Well

I have a unique combination of elements (A B C D E F)

```
from itertools import combinations

data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
comb = combinations(data, 2);

d = [];
for i in comb:
    d.append([i[0], i[1]]);

print d
```

This returns to me:

```
[['A', 'B'], 
 ['A', 'C'], 
 ['A', 'D'],
 ['A', 'E'],
 ['A', 'F'],
 ['B', 'C'],
 ['B', 'D'],
 ['B', 'E'],
 ['B', 'F'],
 ['C', 'D'],
 ['C', 'E'],
 ['C', 'F'],
 ['D', 'E'],
 ['D', 'F'],
 ['E', 'F']]
```

The question is, how to sort this in a way that the line N do not repeat element [0] or element [1] of line (N-1)...in a simpler way:

```
AB (This line can have any element)
CD (This line can't have A or B)
EF (This line can't have C or D)
AC (This line can't have E or F)
...
```

Comment: You don't need to put semicolons at the end of statements (and you shouldn't). Also, you can generate the combinations list `d` simply using `d = map(list, combinations(data, 2))`.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik Why shouldn't use semicolons? And Thanks :D

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ Sorry for taking your time, I just started to think that is impossible to organize in the way that I want...now I`m trying to do some math calcs to verify this...

Comment: @user3701822: You shouldn't use semicolons because it serves no purpose and violates python style conventions. It's frowned upon...

Comment: @JayanthKoushik ah, I normally use because two reasons, one is because a habit of C and PHP, the other reason is because somethimes I code multiples things in same line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mylist= [['A', 'B'],
 ['A', 'C'], 
 ['A', 'D'],
 ['A', 'E'],
 ['A', 'F'],
 ['B', 'C'],
 ['B', 'D'],
 ['B', 'E'],
 ['B', 'F'],
 ['C', 'D'],
 ['C', 'E'],
 ['C', 'F'],
 ['D', 'E'],
 ['D', 'F'],
 ['E', 'F']] 


a=mylist[:] #this used to assign all elements to a so u have ur mylist safe    
b=[]
b.append(a[0]) #this appends the first list in the list
del a[0]  #now deleting appended list        
while len(a)>0:
    for val,i in enumerate(a):# enumerte gives index and value of list
        if len(set(b[len(b)-1]).intersection(set(i)))==0: # this checks intersection so that both list should not have same elements
            b.append(a[val])
            del a[val]
print b

#output [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'E'], ['D', 'F'], ['A', 'E'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['A', 'F'], ['B', 'E'], ['C', 'F'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'F']]
```

Comment: Thanks man! You solved the problem, I will study your code. :D

Comment: @user3701822 be aware that this deletes entries in `a`

Answer (score 2):

Using the neighborhood generator from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323910/1843331) you can get the previous, current and next element in your loop, so that you can compare them. Then you can do something like this

```
from itertools import combinations

# Credit to Markus Jarderot for this function
def neighborhood(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    prev = None
    item = iterator.next()  # throws StopIteration if empty.
    for next in iterator:
        yield (prev,item,next)
        prev = item
        item = next
        # this can be written like this also prev,item=item,next
    yield (prev,item,None)

data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
comb = combinations(data, 2);

d = [];
for prev, item, next in neighborhood(comb):
    # If prev and item both exist and neither are in the last element in d
    if prev and item and not any(x in d[-1] for x in item):
        d.append([item[0], item[1]])
    elif item and not prev: # For the first element
        d.append([item[0], item[1]])

print d
```

This prints

```
[['A', 'B'],
 ['C', 'D'],
 ['E', 'F']]
```

I'm aware this is probably not 100% what you need, but it should be able to get you where you want

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ I know that as you can read in my last line. But an answer can be helpful and useful even if it doesn't provide the full code the OP wants

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ no problem. Your answer works too so ill +1 you

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks to you too man, I'm reading, and this is helpful :)

Comment: @user3701822 good to hear ;-) don't hesitate to upvote useful answers, that goes for sundar's answer, too