# Find the next item of a dictionary in a for loop using .iteritems()

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, iterator

Is it possible to get the next iteritem in a for loop where you loop is

`for x,y dict.iteritems()`

where I'm interested in the next item of x without moving the iterator forward.

In Python 2.7.x

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access previous/next element while for looping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323750/how-to-access-previous-next-element-while-for-looping)

Answer (score 5):

This is more or less a duplicate of the questions [How to access previous/next element while for looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323750/how-to-access-previous-next-element-while-for-looping) and [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434891/iterate-a-list-as-pair-current-next-in-python) .

Note that what follows is solely an adaption of the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323910/955014) in the first thread, adapted to fit your specification:

```
def iterate(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    item = iterator.next()

    for next_item in iterator:
        yield item, next_item
        item = next_item

    yield item, None
```

Usage:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

for item, next_item in iterate(d.iteritems()):
    print item, '| next:', next_item
```

Credit due to [Markus Jarderot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22364/markus-jarderot) for the solution.