# python - extracting tags and attributes from HTML - the hard way

Tags: python, html, regex, parameters, tags

after a long struggling I have managed to get one input long string processed into the following form - one list:

```
['<', 'p', '>', '<', 'a', 'href', '>', '<', 'a', '>', '<', 'p', '>', '<', 'div', 'class', '>', '<', 'a', 'href', '>', '<', 'a', '>', '<', 'div', '>']
```

how can I now efficiently and in hard-coding-way process that list furthermore to get each HTML tag and the attribute it covers ?

so after that i will confirm that p **does not have any attributes**, a has **href** and div has a **class** attribute ?

Comment: Why not use e.g. `BeautifulSoup` in the first place?

Comment: I'm curious.  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?  Perhaps use a parser instead of trying to manually deconstruct html?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just for the sake of academic challenge, you could use (slightly adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323750/how-to-access-previous-next-element-while-for-looping/23531068#23531068) on Stackoverflow)

```
your_list = ['<', 'p', '>', '<', 'a', 'href', '>', '<', 'a', '>', '<', 'p', '>', '<', 'div', 'class', '>', '<', 'a', 'href', '>', '<', 'a', '>', '<', 'div', '>']

for prev,cur,next in zip([None]+your_list[:-1], your_list, your_list[1:]+[None]):
    if prev == '<' and next == '>':
        print "%s is an empty element" % cur
```

**But:** This is certainly not the best/fastest/safest way to achieve your goal, better use an appropriate parser like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) in the first place. That being said, see <kbd>[**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/YmJS1z)</kbd>

Comment: sorry but this displays to me that div is an empty which is not true here.

Comment: @JanM: It correctly prints out the **last** `div`, which is empty indeed.